# getPaymentExecStatus() giving null

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, playframework-2.4

I am trying to use adaptive payment api from paypal java sdk and calling getPaymentExecStatus() giving null. This is my code

```
    final PayRequest payRequest = new PayRequest();
    final List<Receiver> receivers = new ArrayList<Receiver>();
    final Receiver receiver = new Receiver();
    receiver.setAmount(ammount);
    receiver.setEmail("sandeepraju_123@yahoo.co.in");
    receivers.add(receiver);
    final ReceiverList receiverList = new ReceiverList(receivers);
    payRequest.setSenderEmail(Constants.PAYPAL_USER_ID);

    payRequest.setReceiverList(receiverList);

    final RequestEnvelope requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope("en_US");
    payRequest.setRequestEnvelope(requestEnvelope); 
    payRequest.setActionType("PAY");
    payRequest.setCancelUrl("https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_implicit_payment?cancel=true");
    payRequest.setReturnUrl("https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_implicit_payment?success=true");
    payRequest.setCurrencyCode("USD");
    payRequest.setIpnNotificationUrl("http://replaceIpnUrl.com");

    final Map<String, String> sdkConfig = new HashMap<String, String>();
    sdkConfig.put("mode", Constants.PAYPAL_MODE);
    sdkConfig.put("acct1.UserName", Constants.PAYPAL_USER_ID);
    sdkConfig.put("acct1.Password", Constants.PAYPAL_USER_PASSWORD);
    sdkConfig.put("acct1.Signature",Constants.PAYPAL_USER_SIGNATURE);
    sdkConfig.put("acct1.AppId",Constants.PAYPAL_APPID);
    Logger.debug("paypal"+Constants.PAYPAL_USER_ID+Constants.PAYPAL_USER_PASSWORD+Constants.PAYPAL_USER_SIGNATURE); 
    final AdaptivePaymentsService adaptivePaymentsService = new AdaptivePaymentsService(sdkConfig);
    try {
        final PayResponse payResponse = adaptivePaymentsService.pay(payRequest);
        Logger.error("error list"+payResponse.getError());
        Logger.debug("pay respose"+payResponse.toString());
        coachWithdrawl.withdrawlAmount = ammount;
        Logger.debug("payResponse"+payResponse.getPaymentExecStatus());
        coachWithdrawl.paymentExecStatus = payResponse.getPaymentExecStatus();
        coachWithdrawl.payKey = payResponse.getPayKey();
        payResponse.getPaymentExecStatus();
    } catch (SSLConfigurationException | InvalidCredentialException | HttpErrorException
            | InvalidResponseDataException | ClientActionRequiredException | MissingCredentialException
            | IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final com.paypal.sdk.exceptions.OAuthException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I took example from here [paypal implicite example](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_implicit_payment)
and its in sandbox mode so I get credentials from dashboard account tab.
please help me to find why the response and other data comming is null.thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By mistake ,I used paypal user id as the sender id , so it was giving null to get Execution status.thanks though.